# npm package readme display issue

Tags: npm

I just published a package in NPM. **README.md** is displayed fine in **Github** but it's not displayed properly in **NPM README.md** i tried a lot but couldn't figure out any solution. please help me.

[image]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplify-css

https://github.com/Kishor-Kumar-Namdeo/simplify#readme

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I don't know what caused the issue, but what I did is I removed the readme.md from the repository and added it back using github's web interface, pulled the changes and published to npm.

Comment: It did work for me as well.

Comment: This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that file encoding is not supported by npm, particularly if you created it on a Windows machine. Simply save the file with utf-8 encoding and republish.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue.
Here is the solution.

- Open the same README.md in vs code
- In the bottom most, find 'UTF-16'
- click on that
- look at the top, select 'Save with encoding'
- select 'UTF-8' and save
- Run 'npm publish'