# NPM readme file showing up broken

Tags: node.js, npm, package, readme

I have this readme file.

https://pastebin.com/ihH0SKF3

```
It is written in markdown, and there are code blocks in it


Is there something wrong with my readme file?
```

On github, it shows up fine
[image]

But on npmjs.com, it shows up as this

[image]

How do I fix this? Is there something wrong with my embed?

Here is the link for the package if needed
https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-comma?activeTab=readme

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm package readme display issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280276/npm-package-readme-display-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61161811/12892767

To fix this, remove the readme from the repository, re-add the readme through Github's website, then pull the GitHub repository and republish a new version.

Comment: It's better to flag questions as duplicates when you find that the answer to the question already exists on another SO question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Waiting one minute and performing a hard reload (Ctrl + Shift + R) fixed the problem. Possibly just waiting and reloading is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in most cases it is related to file Encoding.
I changed the Encoding to UTF-8 and problem got fixed.

There is a possibility that in the text editor it is set to another encoding format than NPM accepts. change it to UTF-8 or create via the GitHub editor. If you create/Edit your README.md file in GitHub, it will notify you about the encoding and prompt to change it to UTF-8.